# Is there a way to pass a function as a parameter of a macro?

Tags: rust, gtk, rust-decl-macros

I'm trying to write a function similar to `g_signal_connect_swapped` in gtk+.

```
macro_rules! connect_clicked_swap {
    ($widget: tt,$other_widget: expr,$function: ident) => {
        $widget.connect_clicked(|widget| $function($other_widget))
    };
}
```

`ident` doesn't work here since I'd like to pass full path to the function.eg. gtk::ApplicationWindow::close. so I can do something like `connect_clicked_swap!(button, &window, gtk::ApplicationWindow::close)`

Comment: `$function:path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `path` instead of `ident` in order to specify a path. But the most flexible would be to use `expr`, which would accept paths but also expressions that return functions, including closures.

```
macro_rules! connect_clicked_swap {
    ($widget: tt, $other_widget: expr, $function: expr) => {
        $widget.connect_clicked(|widget| $function($other_widget))
    };
}
```

```
connect_clicked_swap!(widget1, widget2, path::to::function);
connect_clicked_swap!(widget1, widget2, |widget| println!("widget = {}", widget);
```